# phonegap push plugin not working after build

Tags: cordova, push-notification, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I'm having trouble to get notification to IOS after downloading the app from phonegap-build.

if I test localy from Xcode it works great. if I download the app from phonegap-build and run it on device I get this on console:

"Use of the  tag has been deprecated. Use a  tag instead. Change:

`<plugin name="PushPlugin" value="PushPlugin" />`

To:

`<feature name="PushPlugin">

 <param name="ios-package" value="PushPlugin" />
 </feature>` "

I have this on www/config.xml:
`<gap:plugin name="com.adobe.plugins.pushplugin" />`

I'm using cordove verion 2.9 with phonegap-build pushPlugin(https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin)

followed this reference:
http://devgirl.org/2012/10/19/tutorial-apple-push-notifications-with-phonegap-part-1/

what am I missing?
please help

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure you've figured this out by now, but if you're using the cloud-based Adobe Phonegap Build, your `<gap:plugin>` name attribute is incorrect. See the [plugin](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/158) page on Adobe's site.

It should be: `<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.pushplugin" />`

Note that the `<gap:plugin>` tags are reserved for the [cloud-based build](https://build.phonegap.com/) service to use when you want it to inject your plugins for you. The local Phonegap CLI is what uses the `<feature>` tags for injecting plugins.

Comment: thanks knightka I've fixed the config xml thing, but now the device console shouts "no valid 'aps-enviorment' entitlement string found...Notifications will not be delivered.
I assume something is not right with the certifications file, I followed this post 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1
but still struggling to get it to work

Comment: @ItaySidis apologies for my delayed response--if my above config.xml solution did indeed solve your Phonegap plugin issue, please mark it as the correct answer for others' reference.   

Were you able to work through your subsequent error? If not, it sounds to me like an issue with your push notifications provisioning setup. Unfortunately, there's a myriad of things the issue could stem from without further information.  A quick search for your error message did turn this up:  

[http://stackoverflow.com/a/14511864/1700790]