# no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application while debugging on xamarin for ios

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, apple-push-notifications, xamarin-studio

I am working on xamarin for ios.

Its was working on my older machine. But, then i had to switch to new machine and recreate all the certificates and everything for the new machine.

I have created the app ID. Then created the aps certificates and then created the provisioning profile.

In Debug I have provided the downloaded provisioning profile. But still I am getting this same error. And my app is unable to get the device token.

I am searching a lot since last night. And have done the following things with no success:

1. Regenerating provisioning profile and trying with the new one
2. I also deleted the app id itself. Recreated everything from start. All Certificates, app id, provisioning profile
3. Deleted all the provisioning profile from my system and device. Created new profiles and installed them.

Above are three most common solutions i found in my searches, but to my dismay nothing is working for me.

If you have any idea please throw at me. I am in a great need for that. Its holding me from submitting the app.

Please help.

Comment: The app id for which i have generated the provisioning profile have push notification enabled for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was xamarin studio itself. It seems that after updating form stable 5.2/5.1 version to 5.3 this issue surfaces. So i deleted the app and installed it again which game me v5.2. Now i am not udpating till i publish my app.

This link is full of people facing this problem:
http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/22502/xamarin-studio-5-3-push-notification-error

Answer (score 1):

did you add the App's Development SSL Certificate to your keychain? when enabling push notifications for the App ID you should generate a Development SSL Certificate for the App, download it and add it to your key chain.

Comment: yeah i have added it to app id from inside of app id. Then i have downloaded and installed it on my system.