# What kind of certificate/provisioning required to test push notification between two devices?

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I followed a basic push notification tutorial and was able to get push notifications working on my own phone with development certs.
(http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1).

I'd like my friend to be able to run the same project code base, retrieve his deviceToken from the console log, and manually execute a PHP file to get a notification on his phone.

So far I tried adding his device UDID to the devices profile and getting him to run the codebase, but he receives the error:

```
 Failed to get token, error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3000 "no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application" UserInfo=0x165665c0 {NSLocalizedDescription=no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application}
```

Should he be able to run the project with my provisioning profiles and certificates? Or do I need to create distribution certs for push services? Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is push notifications enabled on your provisioning profile?

Comment: This might help as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13432203/no-valid-aps-environment-entitlement-string-found-for-application

Comment: There's all sorts of different profiles and certificates between development and production. How are you distributing said app to your friend? If you're using ad-hoc/enterprise then you likely don't have your production certificates and provisioning profiles setup correctly.

Comment: @FawadMasud push notifications are enabled on my provisioning profile.

Comment: @SantaClaus He's running the Xcode project on his own laptop with iPhone plugged in

Comment: If he is compiling the project himself and using a different developer membership then you need to have *his* key installed in your server