# no valid 'aps-envoirnment' entitlement string found for application

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to get device token of my device. When I run app on device, I am getting the following error:

- **no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application**

I have signed app with valid provisioning profile and enabled the option of Push notification.

PS: I have installed the provisioning profile but i don't have the store credentials.

Comment: if the duplicate answer is not work reply here , I reopen the question and we go for next step

Comment: Yes, for me these replies are not working.

Comment: ok , what the error u faced again

Comment: check your provisioning profile. Did you update your certificate & did not update provisioning profile.

Comment: I go to the Preference -> Accounts -> View details, but there is no option of refresh. I also don't have the store credentials, so i can't add account there too. i am again getting error: "no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application".

Comment: And its also confirmed that push notification option enabled in provisioning profile.

Comment: @Gagan_iOS I have regenerated the certificates and the provisioning profile.

Comment: one question , you dont have the **I also don't have the store credentials**, then how did you **regenerated the certificates and the provisioning profile**

Comment: Client did that for me and send me the provisioning profile and certificate. Now i am trying to get device token but i am getting this error.

Comment: ok...then check for Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority (WWDRCA) in your keychain. If it is expired then download new one & install it from  https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer

Comment: @Gagan_iOS, certificate is valid till 2017.

Comment: did you check your keychain? Select show expired from Keychain & recheck.

Comment: @Gagan_iOS Yes, I have checked it from key chain it is valid till March 2017.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13432203/no-valid-aps-environment-entitlement-string-found-for-application)